# Jenkins Slaves in OpenShift

Tags: jenkins

I tried launching Jenkins Master and Slave inside openshift and was able to dynamically provision the slaves.

But when the slaves were configured from Jenkins Master outside of the Openshift, its trigerring the slaves but the slave containers never get created as it keeps looking for jnlp.

Run from slave command line: (when master and slave both are run inside openshift)

java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins-jenkins.example.lab/computer/10be066cb15e4/slave-agent.jnlp -secret d3ba7787316c8733c1bace69b645bbba30aabcd2179c8076c8df320423aff6cc

Run from slave command line: (when master is outside cluster and slave are run inside openshift)

java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myjenkins.com/computer/slave-6b3rp/slave-agent.jnlp -workDir "/opt/jenkins-slave"